# I2C pullup resistors not working in simulation

Tags: pic, i2c, proteus, rtc

I am trying to create a small project on PIC16F877a MCU, in which I am showing the lifetime of this project using RTC module and the temperature read from LM35 onto an LCD.

Working with PULLUP Resistor
[image: Working with PULLUP Resistor]

Not working with 2k pullup resistors
[image: Not working with 2k pullup resistors]

The simulation of this project works fine in Proteus software, when I replace the pullup resistors for the I2C with the component "PULLUP" in the proteus library. But my ultimate goal is to implement this in hardware, so from [I2C pullup resistor calculation formulas](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva689/slva689.pdf), the values calculated for this MCU is as following:

Rp(min) = (5V-0.6V)/8.5mA = 517.6 ohm

Rp(max) = 1/(0.8473)*400*(10^-12)*(10^3) = 2.9 Kohm

using these values from the [MCU datasheet:](http://mech.vub.ac.be/teaching/info/mechatronica/PIC16F87XA.pdf)

tr = 1000ns,
Cb = 400pF,
Iol = 8.5mA,
Vol = 0.6V,
Vcc = 5V

The I2C module is working at 100KHz.

But the issue is that I have tried various values in this range, but the time shown on the LCD remains 00:00:00. Can someone please guide me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think this may just be a modelling issue.

This looks like a Proteus simulation - are you sure the pull-up are not just a logical component, rather than a physically modeled component?  I would check the documentation that came with your software.

Comment: This is a proteus simulation. The `PULLUP` component is from `modelling primitives` library and the `RES` component is from `resistors` library.

Comment: Don't waste time on the vagaries of simulation environments.

Comment: Simulation is a huge step towards completing a project, if such vagaries are common in Proteus software, then it defeats the purpose of simulation. Thank you for your help @N.G.near. Will move on to hardware stage.

Comment: I think the question highlights the difference between logical and physical simulation, so does have some validity.

Comment: Actually, @Mohsin, on the ccs compiler forum, Proteus simulation questions, or programs that have only been run in simulation, are not tolerated at all -- and yes, problems with Proteus often do defeat the purposes of simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have answered your own question!  The fact that the PULLUP is a modelling primitive tells you that it has a logical function and is not a physical component i.e. it tells the simulator something - but it's not a real resistor.

Comment: The funny thing is, I have tried using `RES` from resistors and `Resistor`from modelling primitives library too. The simulation should work for any one of these two components.

Comment: Is it safe to say that in hardware, the project will work with 2Kohm pullup resistors? Is this a negative feature of Proteus that it is not even able to model a resistor or something is wrong in my simulation?

Comment: Not necessarily - logical simulation and physical simulation are not the same thing.  I wouldn't worry too much - it is just how simulators work.  I would refer this to the software support if you are concerned - it could be a bug after all.

Comment: @Mohsin -  this is I2C, so what resistors you can get away with depend on the capacitance on cables on the bus.  A simulation that doesn't model cable capacitance won't help.